# Adding data inside a single column with multiple input fields in LARAVEL

Tags: php, laravel

I am having a hard with this one since it is my first time doing this. What I'm trying to do is to add data inside a single column using multiple input fields, but every time I save the data, the columns are blank, what is the correct way to do it? I'll provide the codes and snippets below.

**Controller.php file**

```
$user = new ApplicantEducModel();
        $user->app_id = $app_id;
        $user->schoolname = Str::upper($request->input(
            [
             'elemSchoolName', 
             'secondarySchoolName', 
             'tertiarySchoolName',
            ]));

        $user->inclusive_year = $request->input(
            [
             'elemSchoolYear',
             'secondarySchoolYear',
             'tertiarySchoolYear',
            ]);
        $user->school_address = Str::upper($request->input(
            [
             'elemAdd',
             'secondaryAdd',
             'tertiaryAdd',
            ]
            ));
```

**Database snippet**
[image: 2 different schools inserted by the same app_id]

Comment: It is better to parse your input value to json object then store them as json string in database field

Comment: see the database snippet for reference. 2 different schools inserted by the same person(app_id). how can i do that?

Comment: I can see only one school name in `schoolname` field. Do you want to add more than one fields in single request? Or merge all 3 type of schoolnames into one and store it in `schoolname` field?

Comment: yes, i want to access more than one field in single request

Comment: It is not possible by your logic. You should use `insert` method to add multiple fields. If you are not familiar with bulk inserting. I can add it as answer

Comment: yes please, can you show that answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do bulk insertation like:

```
$user = ApplicantEducModel::insert([
        [
            'app_id' => $app_id,
            'schoolname' => Str::upper($request->elemSchoolName),
            'inclusive_year' => $request->elemSchoolYear,
            'school_address' => Str::upper($request->elemAdd)
        ],
        [
            'app_id' => $app_id,
            'schoolname' => Str::upper($request->secondarySchoolName),
            'inclusive_year' => $request->secondarySchoolYear,
            'school_address' => Str::upper($request->secondaryAdd)
        ],
        [
            'app_id' => $app_id,
            'schoolname' => Str::upper($request->tertiarySchoolName),
            'inclusive_year' => $request->tertiarySchoolYear,
            'school_address' => Str::upper($request->tertiaryAdd)
        ]
    ]);
```

But first of all make sure these fields are set as `fillable` in `ApplicantEducModel` model. To do that just add below code to your model class:

```
protected $fillable = [
    'app_id',
    'schoolname',
    'inclusive_year',
    'school_address'
];
```